# Relating testimonials to Products

Tags: plugin-craftcommerce

So I am new to Craft and I am attempting a site build with Craft Commerce.
I currently have a channel for Testimonials. Within this I have a relatedProducts field to assign products to testimonials.

What I am trying to achieve is to pull out the specific related testimonials on each specific product page.

Here is the code for my testimonials.

```
{% for testimonial in craft.entries.section('testimonials') %}
<blockquote class="testimonial // testimonial--large">
    {{ testimonial.body }}
    <cite>
        {{ testimonial.citation }}
        {% if testimonial.relatedProducts|length %}
        <span class="testimonial__product">
            {% for testimonial in testimonial.relatedProducts %}
                {{ testimonial.title }}
            {% endfor %}
        </span>
        {% endif %}
    </cite>
</blockquote>
{% endfor %}
```

Is anyone able to assist or offer some guidance on how I can achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It works the same way related entries, (and all other elements) work.

So assuming you are on the products page, and have the `product` variable this should work:

```
{% set relatedTestimonials = craft.entries.section('testimonials').relatedTo(product) %}

{% for testimonial in relatedTestimonials %}
  {{ testimonial.title }}
{% endfor %}
```